# My Relative Div will NOT display a background color or image

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble understanding why my relative div (.wrap) will not display its css defined background color or image. The body has its own background with the .wrap creating a new one for the div and its contents. (**.local is the absolute div I am trying to have .wrap create a background for, as it is one of the many divs I need to have a single shared background from .wrap**) 
Any help will be greatly appriciated!

**CSS**

```
body{
min-height: 100%;
min-width:100%;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background-color: gray;
} 

.wrap {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 70%;
background-color: white;
left: 15%;
}


.local {
position: absolute;
height: 40%;
width: 20%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- MAIN BODY -->
<div class="wrap">

<!-- LOCAL WEATHER -->
<div class="local">
<p>THIS IS A TEST PARAGRAPH TO SHOW THE RELATIVE DIV ISSUE</p>
<!-- <img src="images/weatherphoto.png"> -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add z-index property to you .wrap class like this: .wrap{z-index:99999999} or on your local class. Play with this property. I believe thats is your solution.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work http://prntscr.com/dxfosy heres a link to what it looks like on my end even after adding the z-index... the "THIS IS A TEST PARAGRAPH" is contained inside the .local div and it does not display a white background behind it which is defined in the .wrap div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you absolutely position `.local`, it takes it out of the flow. With it out of the flow, there is nothing inside `.wrap` so it collapses to a height of 0. Since `.wrap` has a height of `0`, and `.local` is out of the flow, `body` has nothing inside it, so it too collapses to a height of `0`.

Using a percentage sets the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) of the element to be a percentage of its containing element. If everything is collapsed, there is nothing to be a percentage of.

If you want `body` to occupy the height of the whole screen, perhaps consider using the `vh` value which is [calculated based on the viewport height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

I beleive updating your `body` style to:

```
body{
    height: 100vh;
    min-width:100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

will give you the outcome you were expecting, because it defines the height of the body as something that is relative to the viewport, which in turn gives `.local` something to be a percentage of.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `wrap` class (in addition to your `local` class actually occupies no height. You specify a `min-height: 100%` in your body, but as body has no parent with a fixed height, that won't do actually ever do anything ;)

What you're actually looking for is `height: 100vh` on body to make sure it occupies 100% of the height of the page. An example of that can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6djqzgyn/).

However, what I would recommend is to instead set the height in the `wrap` class.

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  left: 15%;
}
```

This will bring up the second background colour, as expected :)

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ezvsgztt/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok, so on the height of the body, you cannot use % you have to use px to define the height?

Comment: You can't set a percentage-based height for body, as body has no parent. It's like asking for XX% of 0 -- it will always be 0 ;) I've updated my answer to cover this :)